# Scripted access to Linux clipboard from terminal

Tags: linux, clipboard

I'm using a terminal emulator (**MATE**, to be exact) running on Linux Mint, which is running in a VM hosted by Windows.  I'm connected to a **bash** shell on CentOS Linux via **ssh**.  *I'm not using X-anything.* I am able to copy and paste, using the mouse, between my MATE emulator and Windows.

What I want is to write scripts that can read from, and write to, the buffer that Mint uses for cutting and pasting.  Once upon a time, on some other *nix (Cygwin, perhaps?) it appears like I could read and write **/dev/clipboard**, but there's no such thing in Mint.  Mac OSX has **pbcopy** and **pbpaste**, and there are apparently plenty of solutions when using X-Windows, but none of these seem to address my 'terminal' environment, from all my googling.

I'd like to be able to scrape text from my MATE terminal (or a Windows window, which auto-synchronizes its clipboard with that of Mint) using my mouse, and then run a Perl script that filters that text somehow.  Or conversely, have a script on Mint populate the clipboard allowing me to paste elsewhere.  Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The mouse selection is the `PRIMARY` [**selection**](http://tronche.com/gui/x/icccm/sec-2.html#s-2). The copy selection is the `CLIPBOARD` selection. Both can be accessed with `xclip`.

Comment: I don't seem to have that command.  Isn't that X-windows-related?

Comment: @Chap: Which MATE are you using then?

Comment: The Help>About says MATE 1.2.1 and references http://mate-desktop.org/.  I have utterly no understanding of KDE or GNOME stuff, or whether it's "X" or not.